# Remove Content Type Dropdown

Tags: document-library, content-type, visual-studio-2017

I have deployed some lists and libraries with a feature in visual studio to my on-premise Sharepoint environment.

Whent user uploads a document to a document library, he can change the content typ in a dropdown. Where do I deactivate this in my Visual Studio code?

Answer (score 0):

In library `Schema.xml` you can left only your content type in `ContentTypes` section and remove others.